# MS CSP: Difference between AT_SIGNATURE and RSA_KEY_SIGN (and also AT_KEYEXCHANGE and CALG_RSA_KEYX)

Tags: windows, cryptography, cryptoapi, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm writing CSP library (for CryptoAPI) for smartcards my company sells.

I have question about difference between AT_SIGNATURE key type and CALG_RSA_SIGN algorithm for private key (the same also for AT_KEYEXCHANGE and CALG_RSA_KEYX).

I know what is written on MSDN site, but how specifically CSP DLL should work if either of CALG_RSA... algorithms is specified in call for CPGenKey() function? I mean should it generate session RSA private key or the key should be generated and saved on card? Or maybe it depends on flags specified on CPAcquireContext() call (CRYPT_VERIFY_CONTEXT ie.) and AT_SIGNATURE should be defined as "default algorithm for signature", which for our cards is RSA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not my answer, just found a [good explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/N-Mo8jga4_8) on the Internet:

> AT_SIGNATURE key acn ONLY be used to sign a message. It cannot be used to
>   wrap (export) session key. AT_KEYEXCHANGE key can be used for BOTH purposes.
>   So if you want to use only 1 (one) key pair for both, you definitely need
>   AT_KEYEXCHANGE key pair.
>
> You also need to understand some security implications - and why using two
>   keys are better than using the same key pair for both:
>
> Normally you should NEVER reveal your signing private key. If it is lost, you
>   simply generate a new signing key pair and use that from that point of time.
>   On the other hand, you normally need to back up your key exchange key,
>   because without that you cannot decrypt messages in the future (if the
>   private key is lost). However, backup means that the key may be available to
>   someone else - who now could sign messages purportedly coming from you - and
>   you wouldn't want that.
>   If you use different key pairs for the two actions you can have secure
>   signing (your signing private key never goes out) and still can back up your
>   key exchange key.
>
> One more note on generating these keys:
>   Since you don't want your signing key know, when you generate it with
>   CryptGenKey(AT_SIGNATURE) you should never set flags KEY_EXPORTABLE or
>   KEY_ARCHIVABLE and you may want the extra protection and add
>   CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED, so every time the signing key is used the user knows it.
>   On the other hand, when generating the key exchange key using
>   CryptGenKey(AT_KEYEXCHANGE) you should immediately back it up: set the flag
>   CRYPT_ARCHIVABLE and IMMEDIATELY export the key for backup. (This flag allows
>   to export the key only once - right after it is created -, so it is more
>   secure than allowing to be exported any time by setting CRYPT_EXPORTABLE.)
>
> Laszlo Elteto
>   SafeNet, Inc.